# XQuery_lite for PHP - has anyone managed to get it working?

Tags: php, xquery

I'm attempting to use XQuery with PHP. The only implementation I'm aware of is XQuery_Lite, part of the XMLClasses library, but I'm damned if I can get it to do anything.

The demo.php page that comes with it errors. Whenever I try to execute one of the examples on there, I get:

```
Warning: bib is not visible from here plase use a global string for XML data in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\test\xquery\xquery_lite_2\class_xquery_lite.php on line 201
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\test\xquery\xquery_lite_2\class_xquery_lite.php on line 690
```

I then created this uber-simple script (note: the code came from the read-me PDF, and bib.xml does exist):

```
<?php

$query = '<bib>
{
for $b in document("bib.xml")/bib/book
where $b/publisher = "Addison-Wesley" and $b/@year > 1991
return
<book year="{ $b/@year }">
{ $b/title }
</book>
}
</bib>';

$query = stripslashes($query);
include_once("class_xquery_lite.php");
$xq = new XqueryLite();
$result=$xq->evaluate_xqueryl($query);  

?>
```

...but I'm told that the foreach on line 179 is being fed an empty array. After some digging, this appears to mean the $functions array is empty (in the main class_xquery_lite.php script).

This is all very specific so I don't anticipate anyone can help here, but you never know...

Comment: Can't you help with that, but all major xml databases/xquery processors have PHP interfaces: [BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/PHP_Example), [eXist](http://query-exist.sourceforge.net/), [saxon](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.xsl.php#78436) (this is an incomplete list, have a look at [German wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery#Implementierungen) for more implementations and do some research on how to use them, it's a bunch of links, you will get them). [Disclosure: I'm connected to the BaseX team, but know there are quiet a lot of developers using the PHP-API.]

Comment: Xbase Rocks.. Great future ahead for it!

Comment: It require other library of the phpxmlclasses v1.11 pack, it use adapted DOM methods, like dump_node(), node_name(),... perhaps class_path_parser or other have this class extends DOMDocument... BUT when unzip class_path_parser.tgz, "gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file", "tar: Error is not recoverable".  You have ALL class*.tgz of XQuery_lite?? What the URL for download it??